# python executes mysql script file and passes parameters

Tags: python, mysql

I know how to exeute mysql script file in python, but tried passing parameters and failed.

### Python codes with mysql -e

```
filename = 'test.sql'
cmd = ["mysql", "-h", 'local', "-u", 'user', "-p",'123' ,'-e','set @x=333']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err=process.communicate(str.encode("source "+filename))
```

### test.sql

```
insert into dm.test(a) values(@x);
```

Need help!

Comment: You are not entirely using python here. Why can;t you create a connection and execute SQL?

Comment: Why use `source` here instead of making `process.stdin` point direct to a file handle to `test.sql`?

Comment: @mad_ Above is just an example, indeed, test.sql has hundreds of lines  and is very complicated, I can't execute step and step.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer it by myself after some tries, the correct way is like this:

```
filename = '/bigdata/test.sql'
cmd = ["mysql", "-h", '', "-u", '', "-p",'']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outs,errs=process.communicate(str.encode("set @x=1;source "+filename+";"))
```

The path sep of filename must be unix-style '/'，change to this style when running this on windows.